# Finding the general formula for the sequence following the equations

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

> A complex number $z_n$ ($n=1,2,\dots$) satisfies the following equations:
> $$z_1=1,\quad z_nz_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right)^{n-1}\qquad (n=1,2,\dots)$$

I calculated $z_1\sim z_5$ out to find the general formula, but I am not able to find it.

$$z_1=1,$$

$$z_2=\frac{1}{2},\quad z_1z_2=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right)^0=\frac{1}{2},$$

$$z_3=\frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{4}\cdot 2=\frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{2},\quad z_2z_3=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right)^1=\frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{4},$$

$$z_4=\frac{-1+\sqrt{3}i}{4}\cdot\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{3}i}=-\frac{1-\sqrt{3}i}{2(1+\sqrt{3}i)},\quad z_3z_4=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right)^2=\frac{-2+2\sqrt{3}i}{8}=\frac{-1+\sqrt{3}i}{4},$$

$$z_5=-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left(-\frac{2(1+\sqrt{3}i)}{1-\sqrt{3}i}\right)=\frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{1-\sqrt{3}i},\quad z_4z_5=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right)^3=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{-8}{8}=-\frac{1}{2}.$$

The location of $ 1+\sqrt{3} i$ seems to be related to parity of index. Please help me with the solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What question are you asking?  Are you asking how to compute a closed form expression for $~z_n ~: n \in \{2,3,4,\cdots\}~?$

Comment: Please remove the imbedded images from your posting, and instead express all of the Math with [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Hint: Let $~\displaystyle w = \left( ~\frac{1 + i\sqrt{3}}{2} ~\right) = \left[ ~\cos(\pi/6) + i\sin(\pi/6) ~\right].$  Then, by       [De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula), $~\displaystyle w^n =  \left[ ~\cos(n\pi/6) + i\sin(n\pi/6) ~\right] ~: ~n \in \Bbb{Z^+}.$

Comment: @user2661923 I'm sorry the picture I posted affected reading. Thanks for your reminder.

Comment: @Lorago Thanks for editing this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More generally, let $w$ be a nonzero complex number and consider $$z_n z_{n+1} = \frac{w^{n-1}}{2}, \quad z_1 = 1.$$  Then $$\log z_n + \log z_{n+1} = (n-1) \log w - \log 2$$ and we have the auxiliary recurrence
$$r_{n+1} = (n-1) \log w - \log 2 - r_n$$ where $r_n = \log z_n$.  Now by inspection,
$$\begin{align}
r_{n+1} &= (n-1) \log w - \log 2 - ((n-2) \log w - \log 2 - r_{n-1}) \\
&= \log w + r_{n-1}.
\end{align}$$
So
$$r_{n+2k} = k \log w + r_n$$
for all nonnegative integer $k$, which implies $$r_{2k+1} = k \log w, \\ r_{2k} = (2k-1) \log w - \log 2 - k \log w = (k-1) \log w - \log 2.$$
Converting back to $z$,
$$z_{2k+1} = w^k, \\ z_{2k} = w^{k-1}/2.$$
For your case, $w = e^{\pi i/3}$, which implies that the sequence is periodic, since $w^6 = 1$.  Hence we have
$$
z_{12k+m} = \begin{cases} e^{\pi i (m-2)/6}/2, & m \in \{0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10\} \\
e^{\pi i (m-1)/6}, & m \in \{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11\}. \end{cases}$$
This can be visualized in the complex plane as the following path:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It is really helpful to me.